# How do degenerate states affect molecular absorption?

Tags: spectroscopy, absorption, dipole-moment

Molecular absorption of light is related to the transition dipole moment according to the equation [from Hilborn, 1982](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0202029):
$$\sigma(\omega)=\frac{\pi \omega}{3\epsilon_0\hbar c} \frac{g_2}{g_1}\mu^2\rho(\omega)$$
Where $\sigma$ is the absorption cross section, $\omega$ the excitation frequency, $\mu$ is the transition dipole moment, $\rho$ is the lineshape function, and $g_2/g_1$ is the ratio of degenerate states in the excited/ground energy levels $(\epsilon_0 \hbar c$ are constant$)$.

According to this equation, for molecules with similar dipole moments, but varying the number of excited or ground degenerate states, one would expect the absorption cross section to increase OR decrease compared to the ratio, $(g_2:g_1=1:1)$. I am trying to find examples of such an effect in both directions, but am struggling to do so.

And more on the theory side of things, I find it hard to believe that an additional ground state $(1:2)$ would decrease the absorption cross section, as it would intrinsically introduce an additional possible excitation pathway compared to the $(1:1)$ ratio.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, degenerate states impact molecular absorption by two ways.
One is increasing absorption cross section. More degenerate states in the excited state result in a larger absorption cross section, allowing the molecule to absorb more photons and transition to higher energy levels... Ands the second one is about modifying transition dipole moments. That is degenerate states that can alter the transition dipole moments associated with electronic transitions, affecting the absorption intensity in the molecular system.

I know there is a third way - changing lineshape, but I don't know how it works.

However, remember that it's crucial to consider the specific molecular system and its energy level structure when speaking about the effects of degenerate states:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).